# Make SKSpriteNode flash white with SKAction colorizeWithColor

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

Ok so I have a sprite thats suppose to flash white when hit by something, I'm using this

```
SKAction *changeColorAction = 
[SKAction colorizeWithColor:[SKColor whiteColor] colorBlendFactor:1.0 duration:1];
```

What happens is the sprite flashes, but instead of white, it just turns transparent.
If I use any other color like redColor, blueColor, ect.. It works perfect.

How can I get it to actually turn white?

Thanx for the help!!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colorize with white should give you the image's original colors. It effectively means "no colorizing". You can't colorize it "white". Instead use a texture you prepared that makes the image look brighter.

Comment: Thanx! yeah thats what I've been reading everywhere. ugh. lol :)

Comment: this doesn't work so well if the sprite is animating (e.g. walking). I think an skeffectnode or shader would be needed to animate it white. I think it would be very simple shader but i don't have any skill with glsl shaders.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much for coming up with the alpha trick. Perfect for what I was looking for.

You may use

```
run(SKAction.repeat(SKAction.sequence(changeColorAction,
            waitAction,
            changeBackAction,
            waitAction), count: 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func blink() {

    inviolable = true
    lifeCount--

    if lifeCount <= 0 {

        lifeCount = 0
    }

    var changeColorAction: SKAction = SKAction.runBlock { () -> Void in

        self.alpha = 0.5
    }

    var changeBackAction: SKAction = SKAction.runBlock { () -> Void in

        self.alpha = 1.0
    }

    var waitAction: SKAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.2)

    var finalAction: SKAction = SKAction.runBlock { () -> Void in

        self.inviolable = false
    }

    var combined: SKAction = SKAction.sequence(
        [   changeColorAction,
            waitAction,
            changeBackAction,
            waitAction,
            changeColorAction,
            waitAction,
            changeBackAction,
            waitAction,
            changeColorAction,
            waitAction,
            changeBackAction,
            changeColorAction,
            waitAction,
            changeBackAction,
            changeColorAction,
            waitAction,
            changeBackAction,
            finalAction])

    runAction(combined)
}
```