# SKAction.colorizeWithColor doesn't work on SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, swift, colors, sprite-kit

I'm making an iOS app using and Spritekit to make it, and I have a problem with it.

I am trying to change the color of my **SKShapeNode** by using **SKAction.colorizeWithColor**, but the color of my node won't change at all.

Tried all sorts of things but all of them won't work. Hope to find an answer to this.

This is my code:

```
let changeColorAction = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 1.0)
thesquare.runAction(changeColorAction)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/22029302/1396265 .

Comment: @RainerSchwarze Thank you, but it doesn't work well maybe because mine is a SKShapeNode not a SKSpriteNode..

Comment: I tried it in a different way and could solve the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I vaguely remember this issue being because SKShapeNode simply doesn't work with this action. The class in general is difficult to use and doesn't really fit in well with the universal usability of the SKNode.

Comment: @AndyHeard Yeah, it's not going as planned. I will try another way!